# Send HTML e-mail in App Engine / Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

Can you please give me a simple, and straightforward python example of sending an HTML e-mail using App Engine? Plaintext is straightforward, but I'm having difficulties with HTML tags.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so please forgive any little bugs.  It's based on an example from the Google documentation:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
                            subject="Your account has been approved")

message.to = "Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>"

message.body = """
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
"""

message.html = """
<html><head></head><body>
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
</body></html>
"""

message.send()
```

Comment: If I want to send email to multiple receipients, the docs say it should be a list of strings. Is it like this ['user1@example.com','user2@example2.com']?

It doesn't seem to work for me. Is the format correct?

Answer (score 4):

See this document. This is what you wanted.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html

**html** field of a email message.
**An HTML version of the body content, for recipients that prefer HTML email.**

**attachments** field for email attachments.

Answer (score 0):

This details some issues with sending HTML email on App Engine: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=965

Comment: Not really caring about attachments, or images. Just basic HTML functionality, like <hr> <b>, etc