# GAE: Incoming emails can not preserve format

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I've set up my GAE/Java project to receiving emails and it works pretty fine excepting it can not preserve the incoming mail's format(e.g. bold, italic, font size, text color, bulleted list...), and the content type of incoming mails are always `"text/plain"`, as a result from the end user's view the mail content huddled and unreadable.

For example I send a formatted mail from Gmail, when I receiving the mail in GAE all formats is tripped off and leaves a bulk of plain text.

Is there any way I can get incoming mail type as HTML so the format would be preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860614/send-html-e-mail-in-app-engine-python)

Moreover, I am copying a few excerpts from Google App Engine Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) which says:

```
The message contains a subject, a plaintext body, and an optional HTML body. 
It can also contain file attachments, as well as a limited set of headers.
```

And I am guessing the content type should be `text/html`

Comment: Well, not a duplicated question in your link, that's for sending, mine for receiving, but your highlight input help me out, I just didn't check that type before. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

While sending the mail through server. Set the body content type `text/html`.

```
    .
    .
    .
    htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent("<b>html content</b>", "text/html");
```

This should work for you..